# Return the original object after obj change to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code that change the following object (myDoc) to JQuery,
my question how should I change it after to Java script object(not Jquery) ?

I know that I can store it before but I want to avoid that.

```
this._mDoc = $( myDoc );
```

Comment: `this._mDoc = $( myDoc )[0];` or `this._mDoc = $( myDoc ).get(0);`

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with: `this._mDoc = myDoc;` ???  IMHO, it is not clear what you are asking. EDIT: maybe you want: `this._mDoc[0]`, seems more relevant question then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a **DOM** object from a jQuery object by using the `.get( index )` function. The `index` specifies which elemnt to get (if there are multiple). If you only have one, use `$(myDoc).get(0)`.

You can find more about the `.get()` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

Comment: `get()` returns an array (jq is an array-like object), i guess you meant `get(0)`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Thanks for the notice

Comment: I don't know what he meant by that but the question was how to get a JS (I'm assuming DOM) object from a jQuery object. I think `myDoc` is a JS object he got from either an event or `getElementById()`

Comment: Ya, it's quite confusing question imho

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selector have all possible matched elements in `object` so if want use jquery object in JavaScript then use index of selector.
like `[0]` or other index

```
this._mDoc = $( myDoc )[0];
```

Comment: `myDoc` not cleared in question, may be case `var myDoc = $("<selector>");` and then `$(myDoc)`